# WSO2 bps 3.0.0 how install DSS feature

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

How can I install DSS feature to wso2 bps 3.0.0?
I try with Feature Management using     http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.1/

I get this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: HttpSession is null
        at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.services.prov.utils.ProvWSUtils.getResolutionResult(ProvWSUtils.java:338)
        at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.services.prov.ProvisioningAdminService.performProvisioningAction(ProvisioningAdminService.java:271)
        ... 11 more
[2012-10-06 00:43:26,584] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.ui.ProvisioningAdminClient} -  Error occured while performing provisioning action
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error occured while performing provisioning action
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
        at org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.stub.ProvisioningAdminServiceStub$3.onFault(ProvisioningAdminServiceStub.java:991)
```

Could someone please provide more information on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BPS 3.0.0 and DSS 3.0.0 is not yet released. It will be released in the next few days.